# Nokogiri/Mechanize scraper pass form value into scraper class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, mechanize

As a learning exercise, I built a scraper to fetch Reddit headlines. The current live example can be found [here](http://lit-temple-1691.herokuapp.com) which does not yet include any user-defined functionality. I'd like to add a feature to allow users to enter a preferred subreddit of their choice via a form input. How can I append the subreddit to the url specified in my RedditScraper class? For instance, I'd like to for the base url to be "http:reddit.com/r/" and then a user could enter "ruby" or whatever subreddit they prefer. Here's my scraper class:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'


class RedditScraper

  def initialize
    @headline = []
    @agent = Mechanize.new
  end

  def fetch_reddit_headlines
    @url = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/'
    mech_page = @agent.get(@url)

    num_pages_to_scrape = 2
    count = 0

    while(num_pages_to_scrape > count)
      page = mech_page.parser

      page.css('a.title').each do |link|
        if link['href'].include?('http')
          @headline << { content: link.content, href: link['href'] }
        else
          @headline << { content: link.content, href: "http://reddit.com" + link['href'] }
        end
      end
      @headline

      count += 1
      mech_page = @agent.get(page.css('.nextprev').css('a').last.attributes["href"].value)
    end

    return @headline
  end
end
```

Here's my controller action:

```
def index
    @fetch_reddit = RedditScraper.new.fetch_reddit_headlines
end
```

And my form partial (I followed the example [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)):

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
<%= label_tag(:q, "Enter a Subreddit (example: ruby):") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
<p><%= submit_tag("Retrieve") %></p>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE: Tried suggestion below, but now receiving error: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
def index
  @fetch_reddit = RedditScraper.new.fetch_reddit_headlines(params[:q])
end
```

In RedditScraper

```
def fetch_reddit_headlines(subreddit = 'ruby')
  subreddit = 'ruby' if subreddit.nil?
  @url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/#{subreddit}"

  mech_page = @agent.get(@url)
  (...)
```

In your form

```
  <%= form_tag("/", method: "get") do %>
  (...)
```

If you want to use '/search' in your form, you have to register a path in routes.rb

```
get  'search'  => 'controller#action'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm now receiving the error (updated above)

Comment: Well yes. That can be solved by adding a default value for the argument in fetch_reddit_headlines. Now if no argument is passed in params, it will scrape ruby subreddit. (updated above)

Comment: `subreddit = 'ruby' if subreddit.nil?` should fix that (updated above)

Comment: i'll try this when I get back to my machine